# How to add overlay on scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I am getting
[Screen shot of table with overly in light white color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxWTe.png)

I wanted the overlay div to acquire all the table content

Comment: provide us some of your html and css code, but probably "position: fixed" to overlay div is the answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make put a `div` with below CSS styles.

```
div.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 70vw;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible what I wanted it to be

[end up doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ymDB.png)

Comment: please dont just post link - explain solution here in text as well